# .jks file not found on the specified path

Tags: java, android

I get this sort of an error when I'm trying to Build Signed APK.

> Keystore file /Desktop/my apps/keystore.jks not 
>   found for signing config 'externalOverride'.

Comment: is your selected keystore at specified path?

Comment: check if jks file is present in selected location

Comment: just changed the path and got it, thanks

Comment: change the .jks file and make it again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invalidate caches and restart android studio.